# CSS Deprecate single class when there are 2 classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

There is a div, and it has 2 class names.

like - `<div class="A B">`

What I want is that if there are `.A.B {}`, the it will deprecated `.A{}` AND `.B{}` styles, only use `.A.B{}` style.

Is it possible?

Comment: You would only use `.a.b` in a situation that you would want to override `.a`. The reason to add a second class, is *generally*, to override the first class. Or to make a composite, which `.a.b` already does.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I can't understand what you are trying to say by "What I want is that if there are .A.B {}, the it will deprecated .A{} AND .B{} styles, only use .A.B{} style."

Comment: The term "deprecate" is a bit confusing here. I'd suggest "override" instead.

Answer (score 2):

If an element has class `A`, then it has class `A`, and you can't "turn that off" by adding another class `B`. But I can think of three approaches:

#### "Normal" approach

Define properties in an `.A.B` rule that override the properties in the `.A` or `.B` rules.

```
.A   { color: blue;  }
.B   { color: green; }
.A.B { color: red;   }
```

Or, if you want to "undo" the individual `.A` and `.B` rules when both classes are present, then:

```
.A.B { color: initial; }
```

[`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) is a special value which means, basically, the default value, or the inherited value for inherited properties.

#### Using `all`

There is an `all` shorthand property which refers to all CSS properties. You should probably not use this, because it's sort of a sledgehammer,

```
.A.B { all: initial; }
```

This will reset all properties on `.A.B` elements, including ones that were specified in individual `.A` and `.B` rules, to their initial values. Other values for the `all` property include `inherit` and `unset`. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all) for details.

#### Using `:not`

Another possibility is to rewrite your `A` and `B` rules to exclude the case where both are specified together, by using `:not`. However, this is also a bit of a blunt knife that you may cut yourself with, and it won't scale that well to more classes.

```
.A:not(.B) { /* rules for A by itself */  }
.B:not(.A) { /* rules for B by itself */  }
.A.B       { /* rules for both A and B */ }
```

Comment: The initial value can be used with the specific properties in the "normal" approach, though it comes with the same compat issues that the all property does.

Answer (score 1):

In css whatever comes last takes precedence - that is why it is called a cascading style sheet. The exceptions to this are  if the `!important` flag is used or if the previous selector is more specific than the latter. In your case `.A.B{}` is more specific and so it will automatically override any of the same attributes in `.A{}` and `.B{}`. If you want an attribute in `.B{}` to override an attribute in `.B{}` or vice versa you just need to make sure it comes last.

Comment: It doesn't even matter where .A.B appears since it is more specific than each individual class selector either way.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for catching that mistake. I have edited my answer accordingly.